# Python GraphQL How to declare a self-referencing graphene object type

Tags: python, recursion, graphql

I have a django model which has a foreign key related to itself, I want to represent this model as a graphene `ObjectType`.

I know it is trivial to do this using `DjangoObjectType` from the graphene_django library.

I am looking for an elegant python solution without using graphene_django.

An example of a model I want to represent

```py
# models.py
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=200)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        'self', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True,
        related_name='child_category')
```

the schema below obviously does not scale and the `ParentCategoryType` does not have the `parent` field so it is not strictly a parent of `CategoryType`.

```py
# schema.py
class ParentCategoryType(graphene.ObjectType):
    id = graphene.types.uuid.UUID()
    name = graphene.String()

class CategoryType(graphene.ObjectType):
    id = graphene.types.uuid.UUID()
    name = graphene.String()
    parent = graphene.Field(ParentCategoryType)
```

the code below gives a `CategoryType` undefined error.

```py
#schema.py
class CategoryType(graphene.ObjectType):
    id = graphene.types.uuid.UUID()
    name = graphene.String()
    parent = graphene.Field(CategoryType)
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After doing some research, I came across a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene/issues/110) that tracks this. The answer seems to be [here](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene/issues/110#issuecomment-366515268). I tried this myself and it works. So in your case, you would just change the code to read `parent = graphene.Field(lambda: ParentCategoryType)` and `parent = graphene.Field(lambda: CategoryType)`